# How to use Lipschitz continuity and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove $(∇f(x) − ∇f(y))^T(x − y) ≤ L||x-y||^2$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have seen in a lot of texts that the ''Lipschitz continuity of $∇f$ and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality imply
$(∇f(x) − ∇f(y))^T(x − y) ≤ L||x-y||^2$'' and I was wondering how to prove this using Lipschitz and the Cauchy Inequality?

Comment: $\nabla f(x) \cdot x \leq \|\nabla f(x) \| \|x\| \leq L\|x\|^2 $

Now apply to $x-y$ instead of $x$.

Comment: Apply Cauchy-Shwarz to the LHS of the inequality, and then use the definition of Lipschitz continuity to further bound the resulting norm of the gradient difference.

Answer (score 4):

Cauchy-Schwartz inequality implies that 
$$(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^T (x-y) \leq \|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \|x-y\|.$$
Since the gradient is Lipschitz, we further have 
$$\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq L \| x-y \|,$$
where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant. Combining these gives the result.

Answer (score 2):

If $L$ is a Lipschitz constant for $\nabla f$, then
$$
\begin{split}
(\nabla f(x) − \nabla f(y))^T(x − y)
&=\bigl\langle \nabla f(x) − \nabla f(y),x-y\bigr\rangle \\
&\le \|\nabla f(x) − \nabla f(y)\|\cdot\|x-y\|\\
&\le L||x-y||^2.
\end{split}
$$
The first inequality comes from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Thank you, this makes the result much more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

We have Lipschitz continuity stating that:

$||∇f(x) − ∇f(y)|| \leq L||x-y||$

and Cauchy-Schwartz stating that:

$ u^{T}v= u \cdot v \leq ||u||*||v||$

thus,

$(∇f(x) − ∇f(y))^{T}(x - y) \leq ||(∇f(x) − ∇f(y))|| * ||x - y||$ or

$(∇f(x) − ∇f(y))^{T}(x - y) \leq L||x - y|| * ||x - y|| = L||x-y||^{2}$

Hence proved.